# Add HTML elements into an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add HTML elements in form of variable into an object by using JQuery *or without.

#### HTML elements

```
<a href="#" class="edit">EDIT</a>
```

Now I am just using this elements as variable...

```
var link = "<a href="+'"'+"#"+ '"'+ " class="+'"'+"edit"+'"'+">EDIT</a>";

Obj.addvariable(link) ?????????  // This Object could be any ID Or Class Or Div
```

Comment: @all Thanks to all of you. resolved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### jQuery

```
$('body').append(link);
```

#### JavaScript

```
var element = document.createElement('a');
element.href = 'a';
element.className = 'b'
element.innerHTML = 'EDIT';
document.body.appendChild(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand your question, but maybe [jquery data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can add values to any properties even if they don't exist. javascript automatically creates them for you

```
Obj.anyProperty = 'new value';
```

if you want to append an element to a html element you can either use append:

```
$(element).append(link);
```

or appendTo:

```
$(link).appendTo(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in jquery as

```
$('#elementId').append(link);   // with id
$('.elementClass').append(link);   // with class, append to all elements of this class
```